# Calculate date difference between dates in different rows of a dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

A table looks like this :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HistDT](
    [ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [StartDtSK] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [StartDt] [datetime] NULL,
    [status] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Example data set:

```
ID | StartDtSK | StartDt              | Status |
1     20190520   20-05-2019 12:00:13      10
1     20190520   20-05-2019 10:00:00       5
1     20190414   14-04-2019 13:23:00       2
2     20190312   12-03-2019 10:03:00      10
2     20190308   08-03-2019 18:03:00       1
etc..
```

I need a query which will display the number of days spent in each status. That would be easy if the table i inherited had an end date. I would then calculate the `datediff` and pivot for column `status` values.

Maybe i should create a new table using ssis where i will add an EndDt column which will be the StartDt of the latest added Status.
But is there any way to do this without creating another table?

Comment: Add a few more rows with sample table data, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: Its quite hard to determine the enddate, when we dont have any idea of what it could be. As i can understand its per status. Could you provide some more status examples with the same status value? And why does they have the same ID?

Comment: @Thomas : The way i see it they tried to keep some kind of history of the Status changes. The End date for each row is the start date of the next one. So if it was partitioned by id ordered by Start Date Descending, for row_number 1 the end date would be null. For row_number 2 the end date would be the start date of row_number 1. Will add what you requested too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL Server 2008**

> This is not very pretty, and I haven't tested it for all use cases. I hope you can use it or find inspiration. I'm sure there is a better way :)

```
declare @table2 table (
    [ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [StartDtSK] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [StartDt] [datetime] NULL,
    [status] [nvarchar](30) NULL
) 

insert into @table2

values
(1 ,   '20190520','2019-05-20 12:00:13','10'),


(1 ,   '20190520','2019-05-20 10:00:00','5'),

(1 ,   '20190414','2019-04-14 13:23:00','2'),
(2,     '20190312',   '2019-03-12 10:03:00',      '10'),
(2 ,    '20190308',   '2019-03-08 18:03:00',       '1')

select *,DATEDIFF(dd,startdt,enddate) as TotalDAys from (
select x.ID,StartDtSK,Startdt,[Status],Enddate from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by startdt) as rn from @table2
) x
cross apply ( select * from (select id,StartDt as Enddate,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by startdt) as rn2  from @table2 b
)f where (rn +1 = f.rn2 ) and x.id = f.id ) d

union all
select ID,StartDtSK,startdt,[Status],'9999-12-31' as Enddate from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by startdt desc) as rn from @table2
)X where rn=1
)y 
order by id,startdt
```

**SQL Server 2008 without cross apply**

> This might be a bit more pretty :)

```
select *,DATEDIFF(dd,startdt,enddate) as TotalDAys from (
select x.ID,StartDtSK,Startdt,[Status],case when Enddate is null then '9999-12-31' else Enddate end as Enddate from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by startdt) as rn from @table2
) x
left join ( 
select * from (select id,StartDt as Enddate,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by startdt) as rn2  from @table2 b
)f  ) d on  (rn +1 = d.rn2 ) and x.id = d.id

)y
```

**SQL Server 2012 and above:**

Is this what you want?

```
declare @table2 table (
    [ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [StartDtSK] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [StartDt] [datetime] NULL,
    [status] [nvarchar](30) NULL
) 

insert into @table2

values
(1 ,   '20190520','2019-05-20 12:00:13','10'),


(1 ,   '20190520','2019-05-20 10:00:00','5'),

(1 ,   '20190414','2019-04-14 13:23:00','2')

select *,Datediff(dd,Startdt,Enddate) as TotalDays from (
select *,LAG(StartDt,1,'9999-12-31') over(partition by ID order by StartDT desc) as EndDate from @table2
)x
```

Insert a rule that handles current status (9999-12-31) date

[image]

Comment: Version tag is SQL Server 2008. Lag was introduced in 2012.

Comment: @ZoharPeled well spotted - Didnt see that :/

Comment: that is exactly what i need, just as Zohar said, code has to be sql server 2008 compatible

Comment: @Bonzay ive updated my code - try to see if it works. Its a long shot., and not very pretty.

Comment: @Bonzay Just added new code with a left join instead of my cross apply :) Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Maybe LEAD function is usefull for your question.

Like this

```
IsNull(DateAdd(SECOND,-1,Cast(LEAD ([StartDt],1) OVER (PARTITION BY [status] ORDER BY [StartDt]) AS DATETIME)),getdate()) AS EndDate
```

Comment: Version tag is SQL Server 2008. Lead was introduced in 2012.